# How do I get a count of a unique value in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python

Here is a a shortened example of what my json (list of dictionaries) looks like:

```
[
  {
    "product_type": "widget",
    "id": "1744556-ghh56h-4633",
    "manufacture_id": "AAB4567",
    "language": "en",
    "store_ids": [
      416835,
      456145
    ],
    "name": "Best Widget",
    "origin": "US",
    "manufactured": "2018-08-26",
    "uri": "https://bobswidgets.com/best_widget",
    "image_uris": {
      "small": "https://bobswidgets.com/small/best_widget_sm.jpg",
      "normal": "https://bobswidgets.com/medium/best_widget_md.jpg",
      "large": "https://bobswidgets.com/large/best_widget_lg.jpg"
    },
    "manufacture_cost": "12.50"
  },
  {
    "product_type": "widget",
    "id": "0956786-dje596-3904",
    "manufacture_id": "BCD13D",
    "language": "en",
    "store_ids": [
      "014329",
      "40123"
    ],
    "name": "Best Widget2",
    "origin": "US",
    "manufactured": "2018-10-03",
    "uri": "https://bobswidgets.com/best_widget_2",
    "image_uris": {
      "small": "https://bobswidgets.com/small/best_widget2_sm.jpg",
      "normal": "https://bobswidgets.com/medium/best_widget2_md.jpg",
      "large": "https://bobswidgets.com/large/best_widget2_lg.jpg"
    },
    "manufacture_cost": "13.33"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to get a count of the unique values for a few key:value pairs. I've tried this code and it does a great job of giving the counts for each key but that is  pretty useless since the counts are all nearly the same.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(e.keys() for e in card_dict))
for key, count in counts.most_common():
    print('{}: {}'.format(key, count))
```

I tried this to get values instead of keys but get an error. `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` It's also pretty useless since I have ids in the json file and they are unique.

```
counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(e.values() for e in card_dict))
for value, count in counts.most_common():
    print('{}: {}'.format(value, count))
```

What I want to be able to do is zero in on a handful of keys. For example the language key:value. I'd like to get a count of those that are or are not "en".

The output would be something like:
"The  entities not in English are:"
language : 12345

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What is your input, and what would be the corresponding expected output?

Comment: It sounds like you want this `Counter(chain.from_iterable(e.items() for e in card_dict))`.

Answer (score 0):

In python, tuples are hashable, therefore you can use tuples as keys in a dictionary, moreover `dict.items()` returns `(key, value)` tuples. Using these two remarks, if you change your `count` to:

```py
counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(e.items() for e in card_dict))
```

If some values are actually list of values or simple (non-nested) dictionaries, then you can transform them to tuples before building the `Counter`:

```py
def tuplify(card):
    if isinstance(card, list):
        return tuple(card)
    if isinstance(card, dict):
        return tuple(card.items())
    return card

card_dict = [{k: tuplify(v) for k, v in card.items()} for card in card_dict]
```

Comment: Hmm. Still get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` but I think that is because I may  have oversimplified the json. The full json does have nested lists and dictionaries and that may causing the issue?

Comment: To be more specific, if one of the value is a list, this will fail. On the other hand there are solutions to this, we just the details to discuss them.

Comment: Updated the list of dictionaries to include an idea of what the nested list and dictionaries look like. They are only nest one level lower.

Comment: If your input data is representative, then that should work.

Comment: I used the second block of code you posted and that seems to execute fine but the counter fails. `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`. Were you able to get it to work with my sample data?

Comment: What if I did this? language = [d['language'] for d in card_dict]. That will be just the language and I should be able to do a count on each unique value right?

Comment: i think a simple hack is to push that list I created in my previous comment to a pandas df and then use `df.columnname.unique()`. Good enough for me.